Is there a 'loaded' event in select2 version 4+?
Version 3.5 had a 'select2-loaded' event. Does this type of event also exists on Version 4+? I want to use it for a custom version of select2. Somehow the website of select2 is also down.
Google does not gave me a helpful answer.
